# how to Onclick of <li> close all other <li> elements

Tags: jquery, menu, onclick, html-lists

hi guys i got a question got an ul li memu with a div inside the li on click on a li menu i want to close the other li menu how to do it in jquery please help here is the structure of the elements.

```
<div id="mainmenu" class="menu_container">
                <label class="mobile_collapser">MEN&Uuml;</label>
                <!-- Mobile menu title -->
                <ul>
                     <li class="active"><a href="http://www.website.de">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a>Philosophie</a>
                     <div class="dmui_dropdown_block full_width" style="background-image: url(images/write-feather-icon.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right;">
                     <a class="close" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px;">x</a>
                               <div class="dmui-container">
                                    <div class="dmui-col span3">
                                         <div class="dmui-container">
                                              <ul class="dmui-submenu">
                                                   <li><a href="home_alternative.html">Kundenzufriedenheit</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="page_alternative.html">Preiswürdigkeit</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="gallery.html">Unterstützend</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="portfolio_item.html">Nachhaltig</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="portfolio_item_2.html">Verbindlich</a></li>
                                              </ul>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="dmui-col span3">
                                         <div class="dmui-container">
                                              <ul class="dmui-submenu">
                                                   <li><a href="single_post.html">Philosophie</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="404.html">Qualitätskriterien</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="register.html">Gemeinschaftlich</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="elements.html">Umweltbewusst</a></li>
                                                   <li><a href="documentation/index.html">Leistungsorientiert</a></li>
                                              </ul>
                                         </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
```

Sorry guys here is my Jquery tried out with this version but not working any help ?
edited again here is the full code but still not working could please help ?

```
$(function(){

"use strict";    

var $menu = $('.menu_container'),
    $menu_ul = $('ul', $menu),
    $colapser = $('.mobile_collapser', $menu);

$colapser.on('click', function(){
    $menu_ul.toggleClass('collapsed');
})

var lihasdropdown = $('.menu_container ul li').has( ".dmui_dropdown_block" );
$(lihasdropdown).addClass('has-dropdown');

$(lihasdropdown).on('click', function(){
    $(this).children(".dmui_dropdown_block").toggleClass('show');
    $(this).children(".dmui_dropdown_block").children(".dmui-container").toggleClass('show');
    //insert by me perhaps false              $.not(this).children(".dmui_dropdown_block").removeClass('show');

})
```

});

Comment: Where is `lihasdropdown` defined? `$.not(this)` is not proper syntax, see jQuery API docs

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net, don't need much css for it , just enough to hide whatever is hidden by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/969L66n2/)

```
$(".dmui-submenu").click(function (event)
 {
 event.preventDefault();
 var pos = $(this).closest("ul.dmui-submenu").index(".dmui-submenu");
 if(pos === 1)
 {
    $(".dmui-submenu:eq(0)").hide();
 }
 else
 {
  $(".dmui-submenu:eq(1)").hide(); 
 }
});
```

Not the best approach in case you would have more submenus, but working for the provided example.
`preventDefault()` prevents that the clicked links will work. Using `index(".dmui-submenu")` on `$(this).closest("ul.dmui-submenu")` gets the position of the closest ul with the class submenu, `:eq(x)` will select the ul with the class `dmui-submenu` at the position x.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/index/, http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/, http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Update: Provided answer was matching first version of OP; meanwhile OP was changed 2 times.
Added new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/ejxfu5rs/) with current provided OP js + HTML and added css - classes

```
.show { display:block;}
.hide { display:none;}
```

When using the function `toggleClass('show')`, it is better to have a class named `show`. Otherwise it won't work like intended. As I'm just not sure what the required result is, I'll leave it like that - clicking "Philosophie" in the main menu hides/ shows the submenus; clicking a submenu hides both submenus. I don't think that this is the intention but it would be helpful just to update the question and provide detailed information which submenu(s) should be hidden/shown when clicking which element. I kept console.log messages in the Fiddle, maybe it's helpful just to see which elements will be assigned to the variables to adjust it to whatever the result should look like.

Comment: Thanks man but not working just edited my post perhaps u can help me out again tried it with not.(this) but dont know if syntax is right `$(lihasdropdown).on('click', function(){
        $(this).children(".dmui_dropdown_block").toggleClass('show');
        $(this).children(".dmui_dropdown_block").children(".dmui-container").toggleClass('show');
  $.not(this).children(".dmui_dropdown_block").removeClass('show');

    })`

Comment: first, $(lihasdropdown) won't select anything; if you would add a class lihasdropdown to the ul or li tags it would be $(".lihasdropdown") to select elements having this class